# c parallel processes involving pipe

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int i;

   int fd[2];
   int values[argc - 1];


   for( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ) {
      pipe(fd);

      switch( fork()) { 
      case 0: /* child */
         /* Do stuff */
         close(fd[0]);
         int value = atoi(argv[i]);
         write(fd[1], &value, sizeof(value));
         exit( 0 );
      case -1:
         perror( "fork" );
         exit(1);
      default:  /* parent */
         close(fd[1]);
         read(fd[0], &values[i - 1], sizeof(values[i - 1]));
         /* do stuff, but don't wait() or terminate */
      } 
   }

   for (i = 0; i < (argc - 1); i++)
   {
      printf("%d\n", values[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

im trying to create as many processes as the number of arguments given to the executable and have each process pipe the argument to the parent and store into an array and at the end print out the elements of the array. since the processes run in parallel, when i print out the array elements, the order should be random with respect to the order i entered these elements, but that doesnt seem to be the case as i have ran the executable 1 million times, can someone tell me what the problem is? So someone kindly pointed out that read serializes things, what should i do to make the processes truly parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Your pipe `read` in the parent serializes things.

You (1) create the child; (2) child writes to the pipe; (3) parent will block on `read` until there is something to read.  This repeats for all the children.